# Trying to find a cell value in a google sheets and then return the cell value

Tags: javascript

Getting an TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined (line 35)

I am trying to find a cell value in google sheets and then return the cell value into another cell.

I dont get why I am getting a TypeError and I have tried all forms of toString methods or what not.

Please help

```
function hiearchyRoleGenerator() {
  Logger.log("Setting spreasheets up")
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();

  var generatorSheet = sheets[0];
  var primeSheet = sheets[1];
  var ecsSheet = sheets[2];
  var cloudSalesSheet = sheets[3];
  var salesDevSheet = sheets[4];

  Logger.log("Setting cells up")
  var businessUnit = generatorSheet.getRange("A2").getValue();  
  var startPoint = generatorSheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
  var endPoint = generatorSheet.getRange("C2").getValue();
  var separator = generatorSheet.getRange("D2");
  var concat = generatorSheet.getRange("E2");

  var target = startPoint.toString();
  Logger.log(target)

  //Logger.log("Finding Start Point")
  //Logger.log(startPointResult)
  //Logger.log(String(startPointResult))

  if (businessUnit == "Prime") {
    var lastRow = primeSheet.getLastRow();
    var data = primeSheet.getRange(1,1,lastRow,7).getValues();
    var dataResult = []
    var i,j;
    for (var i = 0; i <= lastRow ;i++) {
      //Logger.log(values[i][0])
      for (var j = 0; j<7; j++){
        //Logger.log(values[i][j])
        if(data[i][j] == startPoint){ //[i] row [j] column ERROR IS HERE
          dataResult.push(data[[i][j]]);
          }
      }
    }

    concat.setValue(dataResult);

  }
}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this?

```
var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,lastRow,7);
var values = range.getValues();

for (var row in values) {
  for (var col in values[row]) {
    if(values[row][column] == startPoint){ //[i] row [j] column ERROR IS HERE
      dataResult.push(values[row][column]);
    }
  }
```

Also row and Column are relative to range so may be using var i,j starting with 0 might be an issue. you might have to use 1 instead

Comment: Thanks, so much it worked :). Can you explain the difference between row and column being relative, as to starting the loop with 0?

Comment: as the row and column are relative to the range itself, the first cell would be values[1][1] and not [0][0]. when you are looping the code might be trying to access [0][0] which is undefined with respect to the range itself.

Comment: cheers for the help, sorry I am a beginner at google app script